# Rspec, Rails, Do I need to get or post a request for every test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm very new to rspec, and rails, and ruby. I'm learning them at the moment. I find myself puting a get or post request in every individual test I perform which isn't very DRY. Do I need to keep issuing these requests for the test to work? or am i missing something fundamental?

EDIT:

For each test I'm performing I have to issue a get :page style request so that the controller will run the request. but when testing various aspects of the same action I repeatedly issue the same request and thus repeat the code. This is not DRY (Don't repeat yourself).

```
describe "Find Movies With Same Director" do
    it "should respond, and find the requested movie" do
      stubFind()
      id = "1"
      get :match_director, :id=>id
      response.code.should eq("200")
    end

    it "should search for movies with the same director" do
      id = "1"
      Movie.should_receive(:match_director).with(id)
      get :match_director, :id=>id
    end

    it "should pass all matching movies to view" do
      id = "1"
      Movie.should_receive(:match_director).with(id).and_return("")
      get :match_director, :id=>id
      assigns[:movies].should not_be nil
    end

    it "should pass a list of movies" do
      id = "1"
      Movie.stub(:match_director).and_return(stub_model(Movie))
      get :match_director, :id=>id

      assigns[:movies].should be_instance_of(Movie)
    end

  end
```

Comment: What specifically isn't DRY? You can move requests for similar tests into `before` blocks (with the caveat that some folks really don't like them). Tests should tend towards being hyper-focused, but without knowing what specifically you're doing, or asking about, it's difficult to provide much in the way of specifics.

Comment: Even more specific detail still would be useful. Can you post a few examples of the code with said repetition? I might make it easier for people to provide you with relevant advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing the same thing for several tests you can move them to a before block.

```
describe 'something' do
    it 'should do one thing' do
        common_thing
        specific_thing
    end

    it 'should do one thing' do
        common_thing
        specific_thing
    end
end
```

becomes

```
describe 'something' do
    before :each do
        common_thing
    end

    it 'should do one thing' do
        specific_thing
    end

    it 'should do one thing' do
        specific_thing
    end
end
```

If you want the common thing to be called only once for all tests then you replace `before :each` with `before :all`.

EDIT: after seeing you edit I think that you could put the call `get :match_director, :id=>id` in a method and use it instead:

```
def call_match_director
    get :match_director, :id=>id
end
```

Then it will be easy to add params to the call in one place. You can also put the id in a variable with the let construct:

```
let(:id) { "1" }
```

All in all like this:

```
describe "Find Movies With Same Director" do
  let(:id) { "1" }

  def call_match_director
    get :match_director, :id=>id
  end

  it "should respond, and find the requested movie" do
    stubFind()
    call_match_director
    response.code.should eq("200")
  end

  it "should search for movies with the same director" do
    Movie.should_receive(:match_director).with(id)
    call_match_director
  end

  it "should pass all matching movies to view" do
    Movie.should_receive(:match_director).with(id).and_return("")
    call_match_director
    assigns[:movies].should not_be nil
  end

  it "should pass a list of movies" do
    Movie.stub(:match_director).and_return(stub_model(Movie))
    call_match_director
    assigns[:movies].should be_instance_of(Movie)
  end
end
```